# Both "fēmina" and "mulier" mean "woman": what's the difference?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, word-comparison, word-choice

The word *fēmina* is used with the meaning "woman":

> Of human beings, a female, woman (cf.: uxor, mulier, matrona; conjux, marita)
>
> ([Lewis and Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/femina))

(*Fēmina* also means "female" when talking about non-human beings.)

*Mulier* also means "woman":

> a woman, a female, whether married or not.
>
> ([Lewis and Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/mulier))

What is the difference (when referring to a person)? When is one used versus the other?

Answer (score 24):

### In Republican and early Imperial Latin, *mulier* was more common, and *fēmina* was more markedly respectful

Although it might seem surprising to speakers of modern languages where using the word "female" instead of "woman" can have a derogatory connotation (as I think can be the case in English, or in Italian*), we have evidence that for Cicero, the word *fēmina* was used to refer to women distinguished by higher social class or virtue, while the more common word *mulier* expressed the sense of "woman" with a neutral or pejorative tone.

However, in later authors we see the word *fēmina* develop a more general sense than that found in Cicero or other Republican authors, impinging on neutral uses previously reserved to *mulier.*

(In authors of all periods, *fēmina* is used with the meaning "female", the antonym of *mās* "male"; thus, an animal can only be described as *fēmina*, and in that context the word has no respectful connotation.)

Quotations from Adams 1972:

- > Latin is unusual in that *femina* tends to be employed rather as a respectful term denoting a woman of moral or social distinction. (page 234)
- > *femina* [...] first occurs extensively in prose as a neutral equivalent of
  > *mulier* in the educated language, from the second century A.D. onwards. In vulgar Latin *mulier* alone had the role of neutral term until much later ... (page 238)
- > In poetry *femina* is already preferred to *mulier* as the neutral term from the Augustan period onwards (page 239)

Quotation from Santoro L'Hoir 1992:

- > *Femina* parallels *vir* in that it is applied specifically to women of the highest rank. Because of the word's aristocratic moral qualities, Cicero sometimes employs it to confirm the respectability of a supportive witness, or to create an atmosphere of sympathetic response for the benefit of the jury-the word *femina* often evoking connotations of helplessness based upon idealized values of femininity. *Mulier,* on the other hand, corresponds to *homo,* being used to indicate members of the
  > lower classes, including freed slaves, foreigners and barbarians. Moreover, Cicero employs the former term with pejorative adjectives for members of the upper classes, as he did the latter to males of the aristocracy, in order to diminish their status. In other words, *mulier,* like *homo,* was used as a term of abuse. (page 30)
- > *Mulier* in reference to women in general is totally neutral. (page 32)

There is further discussion in these two cited works.

### *Mulier* denotes adulthood or maturity and may (but does not always) connote sexual experience

Because *fēmina* means "female", a *puella* is technically a *fēmina*, but is not a *mulier.* Since the word *mulier* has the more specific literal meaning of "adult female human", it can be used to mark a contrast with *puella* "girl" or *virgō* "maiden", "young woman", "virgin".

Adams states

> *Mulier* is often used to denote a mature woman in opposition to
> a *puella:* e.g. *Lex Rib.* 39.3 *ingenuam puellam vel mulierem; Ed. Rothari* 26 *si quis mulieri libere aut puellae in via se anteposuerit*; Fredegarius p. 142.14 *mulierum et puellarum suggestionibus; Leg. Visigothorum* p. 127.9 *in puelle vel mulieris nomine*. From here it was a simple step for the word to take on an implication that the mature woman in question was also sexually experienced. Hence its use at all periods in opposition to *virgo.*
>
> But this latter usage is sporadic and determined by the context. *Mulier* can equally well be employed, even outside Biblical Latin, of an adult woman who has not had intercourse (page 248; footnotes omitted)

### Uses in later, Christian authors

It appears that after a certain point, the respectful sense of "fēmina" becomes less felt, and it seems harder to say how the words may have been distinguished in meaning from then on—or if they even were at all.

Adams's section II "The Emphatic use of *Mulier* and *Femina*" discusses the gradual rise of *femina* used in opposition to *vir*; *mulier* was by was by far the preferred word in this context in Republican Latin, but we have evidence that *vir(i)* vs. *femina(e)* became a typical pairing during later periods (pages 242-249).

Adams notes that

> Quintilian, while preferring *vir*/*femina* to *vir/mulier* (at 9.4.23 he comments on *viri ac feminae* in terms which imply that it had become a fixed phrase: *est et alius naturalis ordo, ut 'viros ac feminas', 'diem ac noctem', 'ortum et occasum' dicas potius, quamquam et retrorsum*) continues to use *mulier* emphatically as often as *femina*

(page 244)

#### Augustine

Augustine interprets certain instances of *mulier* in the Vulgate (which generally uses it consistently to express the basic sense "women") as a Hebraism (Adams, page 247), which seems to indicate that in his time the frequency of the word *fēmina* had increased, and perhaps that of *mulier* had declined. In particular, Augustine seems to find the use of *mulier* to refer to Mary worthy of comment, given that she was a *virgō* (see below on the potential use of *mulier* in opposition to *virgō*). However, Adams points out that

> Even Augustine himself sometimes employs *mulier* as a general term which obviously includes both virgins and non-virgins: e.g. *Civ. Dei.* 3.17 *atque in tarda strage bellorumetiam pestilentia gravis exorta est mulierum;* 1.26 *de mollibus eidem Matri Magnae contra omnem virorum mulierumque verecundiam consecratis;* 16.28 *si femina ita sit provectioris aetatis, ut ei solita mulierum adhuc fluant.* (page 248)

#### Jerome

[Jerome's *Vita Malchi*](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/podcasts/jerome-vita-malchi-1-read-aloud-cf) apparently uses *mulier* or *muliercula* most of the time to refer to a certain virtuous female character in the story, *femina* once in a context that emphasizes her virtue; he also uses *feminae* next to *viri* in a list of people (Haskins & Kritzinger 2018:2):

The two contexts where Jerome uses *femina* in this story are as follows:

- > 4.1 “Dē Beroeā Edessam pergentibus, vīcīna est pūblicō itinerī sōlitūdō, per quam Saracēnī, incertīs semper sēdibus, hūc atque illūc vagantur. Quae suspīciō frequentiam in illīs locīs viātōrum congregat, ut imminēns perīculum auxiliō mūtuō dēclīnētur. Erant in comitātū meō virī, **fēminae,** senēs, iuvenēs, parvulī, numerō circiter septuāgintā.
- ... There were in my company men, **women,** old, young, little ones, about seventy in number.
- > 6.8 Fateor, obstipuī: et admīrātus virtūtem **fēminae**, coniuge plūs amāvī.
- I confess, I was astonished: and admiring the **woman**'s virtue, I loved her more than a wife.

Adams says

> In his *Epistles* Jerome prefers the emphatic use of *femina* to that of *mulier* in the proportion of about 2:1; but in the Vulgate, including that of the O.T., he has a marked preference for *mulier.* (page 246)

#### *Scala coeli*

Apparently, in the *Scala coeli* of Johannes Gobi the younger, a book of *exempla* (a Christian genre of short morally illustrative stories) written around 1327–1330 in the South of France, the stories demonstrating women's faults are presented under the header "femina" (the stories are arranged by topic) while stories demonstrating their virtues are presented under the header "mulier" (Polo de Beaulieu 1999:6). Gobi includes a note "Notandum quod hic ponuntur omnes male conditiones mulierum, sed postea ubi tangitur de ista dictione mulier ponuntur omnes bone conditiones earum." The word *femina* is employed rarely by this author in general: only 5 times (once neutrally, four times in a negative context) as opposed to 229 uses of *mulier* (Polo de Beaulieu 1999:8). Given the misogyny of the text, there are also many instances where *mulier* is used in a negative context. Thus, I would say that Gobi's usage does not exactly show a complete reversal of the Republican usage (*mulier* seems to be the more common and neutral word in both), but it does suggest that for Gobi the term *fēmina* no longer had any special respectful connotation, unless we are to suppose it was being used ironically.

### Works cited

Adams, J. N. (1972). Latin Words for “Woman” and “Wife.” *Glotta,* 50(3/4), 234–255. http://www.jstor.org/stable/40266240

Santoro L'Hoir, Francesca (1992). *The Rhetoric of Gender Terms: 'Man', 'Woman', and the Portrayal of Character in Latin Prose*, second chapter "The obscene *mulier* and the not-heard *femina:* Cicero’s feminine terminology and comic prototypes" (pages 29–46). DOI: https://doi.org/10.1163/9789004329164_004

Polo de Beaulieu, Marie-Anne (1999) "Mulier et femina : les dénominations de la femme dans un recueil d’exempla, l’Echelle du Ciel de Jean Gobi Le Jeune" in *Éducation, prédication et cultures au Moyen Âge: Essai sur Jean Gobi le Jeune* [online]. Lyon: Presses universitaires de Lyon. Available on the Internet: http://books.openedition.org/pul/20010. ISBN: 9782729710590. DOI: https://doi.org/10.4000/books.pul.20010.

Haskins, Susan L., & Kritzinger, Jacobus P.K.. (2018). *Naming the nameless woman of Jerome's Vita Malchi.* HTS Theological Studies, 74(3), 1-7. https://dx.doi.org/10.4102/hts.v74i3.5006

---

*In Italian, the general word for "woman" has become *donna*. Here are some comments by Italian speakers on the rude connotation in modern Italian of using "femmina" in place of "donna":

- "You can call someone a ‘femmina,’ but it’s not the nicest way to address a woman- it’s like saying ‘Hey, female!’" -Flavia Brunetti Proietti "[WORD OF THE DAY: THIS ONE’S FOR THE LADIES](https://whichwaytorome.com/2012/03/08/word-of-the-day-this-ones-for-the-ladies/)", posted March 8, 2012 on the blog "Which Way to Rome?"
- "It is quite offensive to call a woman "femmina". It is demeaning. Source: I am an Italian woman." -zuppaiaia, Oct 24, 2018, comment on "[Femina versus Mulier?](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/9r252b/femina_versus_mulier/)", Reddit post on r/latin

Comment: I saw the exchange in the other question, and was going to suggest this very thing! Curious though, why did you answer it as a community wiki answer?

Comment: "In vulgar Latin *mulier* alone had the role of neutral term until much later" - I think this quote is important for the overall thesis. I also wonder, as I haven't read the article yet, how he deals with Cic. *DND* 2.128.1?

Comment: @cmw: it looks to me like that is case of "femina" in the sense "female" rather than "woman": it's used in coordination with *mas* "male". When speaking of physical sex in animals (or plants), only "femina" is possible and it doesn't have a respectful connotation in that context.

Comment: Right. It seems strange to me that the "respectful" word for people is the neutral one for animals. It makes me think something more is going on with these words than a simple dichotomy, especially since much of this interpretation is coming from Cicero's philosophical works.

Comment: Fun fact: even in modern Romanian, "femeie" is the commonly used word for "woman", while "muiere" sounds both old-fashioned and offensive.

Comment: @vsz: Oddly enough, "femeie" is supposed to have a separate etymology from Latin  *familia.* It's hard to believe, but it doesn't come from *fēmina*!

Comment: @cmw my first thought was that it's an example of reverse Euphemism Treadmill—the more "proper" term was used in more "proper" or academic contexts, and eventually became more and more associated with stuffy/academic/scientific usages and the more vulgar term, combined with English's gradual loss of formality distinguishers (you/thou, etc) took over common usage. That's entirely conjecture on my part, however.

Comment: I removed CW status. What's a shame is that you don't get points for the upvotes! If this turns into a long-standing, much edited post, we can go back there, but I think in the meantime you should get the credit for doing this work.