# Both 'masculus' and 'vir' mean man/male: what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, declension, history, names, gender

In Latin, masculus means male.

> Noun masculus m (genitive masculī); second declension
>
> - a male (of humans or other animals)

In Latin, vir also means male.

> Noun vir m (genitive virī); second declension
>
> - man in the sense of "adult male human": adult, mature or grown man

What is the difference between the two?

Would it have been appropriate for a Roman to name their son either Masculus or Vir?

Comment: Related: [Both "fēmina" and "mulier" mean "woman": what's the difference?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/19476/11674)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Vir* means "man" and is used as a noun. It is a very common word.

*Masculus* can be translated as "male" or "masculine"; it is used as a noun or adjective, and is less common than *vir.* Lewis and Short observes that this word is "not in Cic[ero] or Caes[ar]". In form, *masculus* is a diminutive of *mas,* which also means "male".

The most obvious difference, which is indicated in the cited definitions, is that you couldn't use *vir* if you're talking about an animal or any other kind of non-human being that couldn't be described as a "man". Also, as far as I know, *vir* is not used as an adjective (although Latin sometimes uses two nouns in apposition in ways that look similar to a noun + adjective).

#### *Masculus* could be a male *cognomen*

Roman names are complicated. *Masculus* is attested as a male name in Latin, but I'm not sure how often it would have been chosen by the individual's parents.

The naming system for men that is generally associated with Classical Rome has three parts ("tria nomina"). The first part, the *praenomen*, was a given name (which I assume could be chosen by the parents, although appparently, [it could be chosen instead by the *pater familias*](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/roman_names.html)), but the *praenomen* conventionally was chosen from a fairly small and closed list of names, covered [here by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenomen#Masculine_names). "Masculus" or "Vir" would not be a standard *praenomen.*

The second part of a male Roman citizen's name, the *nomen gentilicium,* was not chosen: rather, it was inherited from one's father. (Or was granted somehow upon acquisition of citizenship for new Roman citizens—I'm not sure what customs were followed in this case, although I found some discussion [here](https://www.pompeiiinpictures.com/pompeiiinpictures/R0/Roman%20Personal%20Names.htm).) These names typically ended in *-ius.* It seems like there are some attestations of forms derived from *Masculus* as a *nomen.* Gavrielatos (linked below) mentions *Masclius Balbus* (p. 107). "Masclinius" is attested in the name "[Masclinius Masculus](https://books.google.com/books?id=MF0KAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA118)".

The third name in the *tria nomina* was called the *cognomen.* It's not very clear to me when and how a *cognomen* was bestowed. Descriptions of Roman naming systems seem to often characterize the *cognomen* as originally being a "nickname" or epithet but it seems to have become common from fairly early on for these names to be inherited within a family. I found an article that suggests the *cognomen* might be chosen by one's parents in certain periods:

> from about 100 B.C. native Romans began to give their children diacritic cognomina at birth. Native Romans used the new cognomen to indulge in new coinages, often formed, like an adoptee's cognomen, from a gentilicium.

("What's in a Name? A Survey of Roman Onomastic Practice from c. 700 B.C. to A.D. 700", Benet Salway, *The Journal of Roman Studies,* Vol. 84 (1994), page 128)

*[Masculus](https://www.therthdimension.org/AncientRome/RomanNaming/romannaming.htm)* is attested as a cognomen, and perhaps also as a name outside of the conventional Roman citizen naming system. I'm not sure whether there are records of how the name was bestowed on the historical figures that bore it.
"[Names on Gallo-Roman Terra Sigillata (1st – 3rd C. A.D.)](https://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/4448/1/Gavrielatos_Thesis.pdf)", by Andreas Gavrielatos (2012), mentions "L. Tr- Masculus" as the name of a potter.

"[Lost Along the Way: A Centurion *Domo Britannia* in Bostra](https://www.academia.edu/26008318/L_E_Tacoma_T_Ivleva_D_J_Breeze_Lost_Along_the_Way_A_Centurion_Domo_Britannia_in_Bostra_Britannia_47_2016_31_42)" (Laurens E. Tacoma, Tatiana Ivleva, David J. Breeze) says in fact that "Masculus [...] is a very common name that can be found almost anywhere in the empire" (note 15, page 17).

*Masculus* (or *Masclus*) appears as a personal name in the [Tab.Vindol. III, 628](https://romaninscriptionsofbritain.org/inscriptions/TabVindol628),
a letter written in Latin from a decurion of the *cohors VIIII batavorum equitata* named Masculus to the prefect Flavius Cerialis. Cuff 2011 ("[The King of the Batavians: Remarks on Tab. Vindol. III](https://www.academia.edu/9031169/The_King_of_the_Batavians_Remarks_on_Tab_Vindol_III_628), 628. Britannia, 42, pp 145-156) suggests the name was "perhaps a translation of a Germanic word expressing the equivalent value of manliness" (page 149). Cuff infers that the author of the letter was not a Roman citizen, and so *Masculus* in this context would be a single name (page 154), not part of the Roman *tria nomina* naming system.

#### names based on *vir*: *Virilis, Viratus, Virtus*

I don't know if *vir* itself is attested as a *cognomen,* but there are several names based on it that are.

*Virilis* seems to be attested as a *cognomen*:

> For the *cognomen* of Virilis, Kajanto prefers the classification in the category of *Cognomina relating to the human body* pointing a manly, virile character or manhood in general. It is an adjective used as a cognomen due to the parents’ hopes for the child or to the acquiring of a laudatory nickname. The frequency of the name in CIL XII and XIII implies some connection with the Celtic name *Virillus.* This connection is simply the Gaulish stem *-viro-* (‘man’), which is homonym with the Latin *vir, -i.* The cognomen *Virilis* is certainly Latin, obtained from the Latin adjective *virilis, -e.* Its popularity is therefore resulted by the fact that it resembles the Gaulish formations and therefore, Gauls who had a similar Gaulish name, could likely have acquired the *Deckname* Virilis, as a way of Latinising their names.

(Gavrielatos pp. 95-96)

It seems *Viratus* could also be a cognomen (CIL V, 7299, cited by "[Remarks on the personal names](https://www.persee.fr/doc/ecelt_0373-1928_2013_num_39_1_2404)", Karin Stüber, in: Etudes Celtiques, vol. 39, 2013. pp. 161-168, doi : https://doi.org/10.3406/ecelt.2013.2404, page 163).

Gavrielatos also mentions a single example of *Virtus* used as a *cognomen* in the name Tabius Virtus, noting

> *Virtus* is not otherwise known as a *cognomen*. It is possible however, to consider a Gaulish *Virutis* (adapted to Latin morphology) or *Virotos/ -us* with syncope of the /u/ or /o/. If so, it is derived from the Gaulish *viros* (‘man’, ‘true?’) and it apparently used as a Latin homonym (Deckname)

(pp. 133-134).

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the difference between _masculus_ and _vir_ is similar to the difference between the English words _male_ and _man_?

Comment: @Adam that's along the right lines, though "man" has too many shades of meaning in English to really highlight the difference. However the adjective "manly" and phrases like "real man" still carry the sense intended by "vir".